# Datagrid Column Dragging Indicator is clipped

Tags: wpf, datagrid, visualbrush

Edit: Pavel has shown that it may not be VisualBrush's fault so I have renamed the question for my specific problem.

The example is a WPF Datagrid;
Scroll right until a column header is partially visible.
drag the partially visible column header to reorder it.
the drag indicator is the partial view of the header (not complete)

**My Solution** - Still interested in other solutions

I subscribe to ColumnReordering and replace the drag indicator with my own.
Copying the source of DataGridColumnFloatingHeader for my own class.
I change the line that creates the visual brush using the header, to a line that creates the visual brush using the first child of the header (which is not clipped)
remove the offset and use 0,0..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**

I believe it is a bug in DataGrid implementation. I suggest you scroll on column start to avoid such unwanted behaviour if it really treats you.

IMHO problem itself is in `System.Windows.Controls.DataGridColumnFloatingHeader`. Due this class is internal it is hard to workaround the problem.

**How to reproduce:**

Scroll a bit right, than drag first column.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="300">

    <ScrollViewer x:Name="uiScroll">
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="3" x:Name="uiGrid">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="200" Header="Test 1" Binding="{Binding Key}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="200" Header="Test 2" Binding="{Binding Value}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </ScrollViewer>

</Window>
```

...

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        uiGrid.ItemsSource = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "key1", "val1" }, { "key2", "val2" } };
    }

}
```

Comment: The issue must have something to do with the ScrollViewer. Give your grid an itemssource, scroll right until a column is half visible, drag it. Voila!

Comment: Your using a stackpanel, the content won't be clipped

Comment: I have replaced that internal class with my own implementation (on column reordering event) However I still can't get it to work correctly.